# Image is not updating in app

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

In my app I have one page from where user can update his profile picture . And in another page I have also display that profile picture. I am using user id to save profile image like **1.png** so it name will be same every time . Now I am using UIImageView+AFnetworking.h and I am settign image byu this code:

```
NSString *urlString=[ImageURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"profile-picture"]];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
[imgProfile setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"No_image"]];
```

Now when I update picture and go to another page to see updated profile picture it is displaying old one . and when I goes back to page where user can update picture there also old image is shown. And when I type directly image link to browser it is showing updat4ed image there on server. So image is updated to server  but not not updating to app. I  think it is may be because each and every time url will be same so that class will not reload data from there . Am I write? and if yes then what should I do to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but maybe you're initializing the profile picture only once the page loads the first time. As long as the view hierarchy doesn't get unloaded (which won't necessarily happen if you just switch between view controllers), the UIImageView showing your profile picture has no reason to reload its ressource.

So you might want to check within viewWillAppear whether your image has changed and reload it if necessary, or skip this step and just reload the image every time the page becomes visible.

Again, this is just a guess - please tell us more about how you save and load the image if this didn't do the trick.

Comment: no....I was correct...That class has method that store cache for request...When I return nil value to that it is now loading every time if image change.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that your request caches the old image.
When you set your new image and then want to get it from the server you get the
old cached version.

You could try to disable caching for this requests.